Using moment with Angular 18
After upgrading to Angular 18 I get following error when using moment.
Calling "moment" will crash at run-time because it's an import namespace object, not a function
My import statement looks as following
import * as moment from 'moment';
using moment looks like this
moment(this.to.val, this.validTimeFormats, true).isValid()
Any help?

please update the question with a stackblitz where the issue happens or github repo

could not reproduce it in stackblitz

seems to be just a warning as per this github issue, try date-fns. which can do the same thing as moment.

After opening the application i get following error in the console:
moment6 is not a function at _CockpitComponent.getWeekday

When updating to version 18 angular adds esModuleInterop to the tsconfig.json
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#esModuleInterop
According to documentation either remove it or import moment as
import moment from 'moment';


When you use import * as moment from 'moment', you're importing the entire library as a namespace object, not the moment function itself. This leads to a runtime error because you're trying to call moment as a function, but it's not one.
Import the moment function directly:


import moment from 'moment';



